# Is it possible to directly connect a grpc client through L4 LB with GKE without ESP?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, grpc

What I try to do with GKE is:

GRPC client -> L4 LB -> GRPC server (inside a pod)

I tried and get 'connection refused' on the client side.

It works fine with an ESPv1 (Extensible Service Proxy - google endpoint component which uses nginx).

I would like to know if someone succeeded in doing so or if you have an explanation to why it cannot work without the ESP.

I can post my configuration if needed.

---

### Update

A solution with nginx has been proposed. ESP is including an nginx too, so I would like to know if it's possible to avoid an nginx or any proxy/reverse proxy and if no, why?

What is nginx doing to make the grpc connection work?

Comment: Did you try to investigate it using `tcpdump` on your GRPC server ? It could probably tell you quite a lot about the reason why connection is getting refused.

Comment: @mario yes I did, but I am going to double check. I guess if there is traffic, it should come from the L4 LB, right?

Comment: Yes, I suppose so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should (!?) work without a proxy. I'm confident I've done this but I was unable to find a blog post that I'd written to share with you. I don't recall an obvious reason why a L4 LB wouldn't work (L7 is a different story because of HTTP/2).

There's certainly no requirement on the use of NGINX; the latest version of ESP (as with many other proxies at Google) now uses Envoy.

Can you connect to one of the service's pods directly? You can try `kubectl port-forward` to the pod and then use that endpoint:port directly from the client.

You may wish to use [`grpcurl`](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) to avoid having to use your client for testing.

Using an L4 load-balancer does not give you gRPC load balancing, of course.

Comment: Actually I tried with telepresence, it's similar to port-forward. And it's working this way. Currently, I get a connection_refused on port 443 from outside. 
Also I noticed that the L4 actually gives me load-balancing by connecting to a random pod. After that the connection remains on that pod which is fine

Comment: Also I use Espv1 which uses nginx.

Comment: `:443` suggests TLS and this may be problematic. ESP terminates the TLS connection but the L4 does not (to my knowledge). You asked whether you can drop ESP and I think you can. I'm going to try to test this now.

Comment: Actually I moved the TLS temination to the GRPC server inside the pod. It works with telepresence but not inside GKE. It's not mTLS, just TLS, with a domain cert.

Comment: Hmmm... I created an insecure service and it works through the L4. If I can grab more time, I'll try securing the service.

Comment: I added TLS (not mTLS) to the client and server, redeployed and am able to connect through the L4 directly to the gRPC server deployment.

Comment: Ok cool thx a lot! I have a domain cert, I guess yours is a self-signed? Maybe the error I face is due to the fact that the cert is attached to a domain and requires extra validation.

Comment: I'm using a LetsEncrypt domain cert

Comment: If you gmail me (same identity as here) your GitHub identity, I'll add you to my repo so that you can see what I did.